# How to display next record from database

Tags: java, jdbc

```
try {
    if ( rs.next( ) ) {
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String first = rs.getString("First_Name");
        String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");
        String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");
        textID.setText(id);
        textFirstName.setText(first);
        textLastName.setText(last);
        textJobTitle.setText(job);
    }
    else {
        rs.previous( );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, "End of File");
    }
}
catch (SQLException err) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Workers.this, err.getMessage());
}
```

I can't get the next record when i use this code .. it only shows the first record.

Comment: Hi mimi - you need to accept some more of the answers people have been giving you.  Also some more detail would be good.  What language is this in? What do you mean by next record?  At the moment you're only getting a single record once, (see my answer).  Do you want to get each of them one by one?

Comment: Also please pay more attention when you choose tags... this is `Java` not jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

try using

```
while(rs.next())
{
    int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");

    String id = Integer.toString(id_col);

    String first = rs.getString("First_Name");

    String last = rs.getString("Last_Name");

    String job = rs.getString("Job_Title");

    ......
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to loop through and show them all one by one, you'll need to use a loop.

You're using an `if` statement on the `next` method, which will only get the next one and then stop.  If you want to get each of them you need to do a loop.